# Wordpress CSS updates appear after delay

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

I am using an FTP client to download/edit/upload CSS files of my child theme. Typically that worked smoothly and updates were seen after refreshing the page in the browser immediately.

However, on my current fresh wordpress install, I see changes in my CSS only after a few minutes, which makes the whole process really annoying. I don't quite know what I am doing wrong.

Here are some details of my setup:

- I use a child-theme which uses the twentythirteen theme as a parent.
- It's definitley not a browser cache issue, since I work on chrome incognito mode with the dev-console opened (and enabled *Disable cache (while DevTools is open)* checkbox)
- One strange thing I observer is, that, when accessing the child theme's CSS file directly in the browser it appears differently sometimes. I suspect, Wordpress is somehow accessing the CSS file and if there was a change, it caches the file and from then on returnes a minified version of the CSS. Maybe this is the root cause of the error. This is what the file actually looks like:

[image]

This is what the *same* file most of the times looks like when accessed via the browser directly:

[image]

- This is the excerpt of the child-theme's functions.php which shows how the child-theme's style is included. Maybe I am doing something wrong here: http://pastebin.com/0MRjTTjf

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Sometime with a fresh install of WordPress from One-click Installer Scripts (like fantastico) , a cache plugin is automatically installed and activated. Check if that's activated or not. If not, check for the line `define('WP_CACHE', true);` in your `wp-config.php` file. If found, set it to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. a) Seems I dont have a cache plugin installed. Only 4 plugins installed, 2 of them are activated (qtranslate, accessibility). see: http://i.imgur.com/nWUhFzd.png
b) in `wp-config.php` I did not find any entry like `define('WP_CACHE', true);`

Comment: Seems like the CSS is being minified somehow. Do you have Apache extensions like mod_pagespeed installed in your server?

Comment: how to check if mod_pagespeed is installed? i dont have SSH access to the machine. this is the output of `phpinfo()`: http://verein-iks.eu/info.php

Comment: These are the raw response-headers: http://pastebin.com/Gsjtk9uU
I see the field `Cache-Control: max-age=280`. Maybe this is the root of the problem. I need to find out, who adds this ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Webhoster has enabled `mod_pagespeed` by default. I had to turn this off via entering `ModPagespeed off` in my `.htaccess` file. Abhik also pointed to this in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669099/wordpress-css-updates-appear-after-delay?noredirect=1#comment55112071_33669099).